# Crop UIImage in shape of a hexagon?

Tags: ios, uiimage, crop

So I have seen solutions for how to crop UIImages into certain shapes, but what about a **hexagon**?

A thought: subclass UIImage, change the drawRect method to only draw certain sections?

EDIT: To be more specific, I hope to keep the image bounds the same, but make the image data outside the hexagon to be transparent, so it *appears* that the image is in the shape of a hexagon, when in reality it has the same rectangular bounds with just part of the image being transparent.

Not sure. Would love to hear what you all think.

Comment: Just for clarification. What do you mean by 'crop' here? The resulting image will still have the bounds as before, so what do you want to happen to the image data outside the hexagon? Do you want it to be transparent and save away the resulting image to disk? Do you want to directly draw the image without parts masked by the hexagon?

Answer (score 9):

Can you put the image in a `UIImageView`? If so:

Create a new `CAShapeLayer` (remember to import QuartzCore!). Create a `CGPathRef` or `UIBezierPath` of a hexagon shape, and set it to the shape layer’s `path` property. Set your shape layer as the [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask) of the image view’s layer.

If you want to modify the `UIImage` itself, you will probably want to add a category method like `- (UIImage)hexagonImage` which draws the image into a `CGGraphicsContext` that is clipped by your hexagon path using [`CGContextClipPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip), and then returns a `UIImage` created from the graphics context.

**Edit**: here are code samples

(Note: I got a little carried away in constructing my answer, and you can see both of the techniques mentioned below, in addition to some code for generating a `UIBezierPath` *n*-gon, in the sample project at [ZEPolygon](https://github.com/ZevEisenberg/ZEPolygon))

Method 1: Mask image view with `CAShapeLayer`

```
UIImageView *maskedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

// insert your code for generating a hexagon here, or use mine from ZEPolygon
UIBezierPath *nonagon = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPolygonInRect:maskedImageView.frame numberOfSides:9];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = nonagon.CGPath;

maskedImageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;

[self.view addSubview:maskedImageView];
```

Method 2: category on `UIImage` to return a masked version

In **`UIImage+PolygonMasking.h`**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (ABCPolygonMasking)

- (UIImage *)abc_imageMaskedWithPolygonWithNumberOfSides:(NSUInteger)numberOfSides;

@end
```

In **`UIImage+PolygonMasking.m`**:

```
#import "UIImage+PolygonMasking.h"
#import "UIBezierPath+ZEPolygon.h"

@implementation UIImage (ABCPolygonMasking)

- (UIImage *)abc_imageMaskedWithPolygonWithNumberOfSides:(NSUInteger)numberOfSides
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // insert your code for generating a hexagon here, or use mine from ZEPolygon
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPolygonInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
                                                     numberOfSides:numberOfSides];

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    [path addClip];
    [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return retImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Zev - thanks so much for the high level overview of what to do. However - I have little to no experience with CA and modifying images. Would you mind posting a code sample when you have the chance? It would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.